# how to display a list that has numbers when the number is inputted

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
options = ["1. Hyundai", "2. Benz", "3. BMW", "4. Honda", "5. Toyota", "6. GMC", "7. Cadillac", "0.Exit"]

for i in options:
    print(i)
answer = int(input("choose a number from the list above "))
for index in range(len(options)):
    if answer == options[0]:
        print(f"{options} is a nice car")


if  answer == 0:
    print("Goodbye")
```

i would like to know how to get the output "(their option) is a nice car" after they put the number of the car they like.

Comment: int `1` is not string `"1. Hyundai"`. Consider using a `dict`? And there is more mistakes at every lines...

Comment: Using `options[0]` won't work when there are more than 10 options. You should use a more general design. Such as just use the input value as an index into the list.

Comment: If the user enters `0`, you'll print `Exit is a nice car`.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = ["1. Hyundai", "2. Benz", "3. BMW", "4. Honda", "5. Toyota", "6. GMC", "7. Cadillac", "0.Exit"]

for i in options:
    print(i)
answer = int(input("choose a number from the list above "))
if  answer == 0:
    print("Goodbye")
else:
    print(f"{options[answer-1]} is a nice car")
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to print "their car", so we don't need answer==options[index], we just need to print options[0] if answer is 1, options[1] if answer is 2, options[2] if answer is 3, and so on, so your edited code would be:

```
options = ["1. Hyundai", "2. Benz", "3. BMW", "4. Honda", "5. Toyota", 
"6. GMC", "7. Cadillac", "0.Exit"]

for i in options:
    print(i)
answer = int(input("choose a number from the list above "))
if answer in range(1,8):
    print(f"{options[answer-1]} is a nice car")


elif  answer == 0:
    print("Goodbye")
else:
    print("wrong option chosen")
```

Check for indentation errors because I've edited it myself while writing answer